# Issue in windows phone 8 : Error 2 SlideView is not supported in a Silverlight project

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have got few issues while trying to implement a sliding menu ('Facebook' like) in my windows phone 8 application.

When I added the following code in app.xaml, it shows following issues

```
<Application.RootVisual>
            <library:SlideApplicationFrame Header="ManageIT"
                                       Background="White">
                <!--<library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
                <pages:LeftView />
            </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>-->
                <!--<library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>
                <pages:RightView />
            </library:SlideApplicationFrame.RightContent>-->
            </library:SlideApplicationFrame>
        </Application.RootVisual>
```

The exception is given below.

```
Error   1   Nested properties are not supported: Application.RootVisual.
Error   2   The attachable property 'RootVisual' was not found in type 'Application'.
Error   3   Unexpected PROPERTYELEMENT in parse rule PropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG..
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Is it because the reference to System.Windows.UIElement is not done?

**Update 1**

I have undone the above change and add the following in mainpage.xaml after installing slideview using package manager console

> Install-Package SlideView

Here is the code...

> `<controls:SlideView>`

```
            <Grid Background="Teal"
            Width="400" />

            <Grid Background="Tomato" />

            <Grid Background="LightYellow" />

            <Grid Background="YellowGreen"
            Width="400"/>

        </controls:SlideView>
```

But I have another set of build errors as follows...

> Error 1   The namespace prefix "controls" is not defined.
>
> **Error   2   SlideView is not supported in a Silverlight project.**
>
> Error 3   The namespace prefix "controls" is not defined.
>
> Error 4   The
>   type 'controls:SlideView' was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
>   been built.

**Update 2**

Got the above issue fixed, but I have some run time exceptions as following...

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=Microsoft.Phone
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame..ctor()
       at slidingmenu.App.InitializePhoneApplication()
       at slidingmenu.App..ctor()
  InnerException:
```

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: NO not yet. If you are interested I will mention the whole steps I have tried.

Comment: i had a little bit time on my hands on friday, so i try to include the library in the actual project, the same error occurred, the way to fix that was by changing `PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame` to `SlideApplicationFrame RootFrame`. If that doesn't work can you show me your `App.cs`?

Comment: Did you remove the <Application.RootVisual> code from app.xaml ? or it still exist there ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the xml namespace defined?

```
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"
    xmlns:slideview3="clr-namespace:slideview3"
```

If LeftView is one of your controls.

```
    <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
        <slideview3:LeftView />
    </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.
Now there are few more exceptions throws from the following code in app.xaml

 <library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>
      <pages:LeftView />
 </library:SlideApplicationFrame.LeftContent>

The exception is given below
1. 'pages' is an undeclared prefix.
2. The property "LeftContent" cannot be empty.
3. The type 'pages:LeftView' was not found. Verify that you are not      missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: is pages declared as an xmlns? That looks like a user control so the namespace must be defined in order to use it.

Comment: got it corrected and ended up in a run time exception...

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=Microsoft.Phone
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame..ctor()
       at slidingmenu.App.InitializePhoneApplication()
       at slidingmenu.App..ctor()
  InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

Try to nest your controls in parent control such as `StackPanel`. Most likely you have messed up the namespaces. What i would do? It will be to compare my code with a working one. CodePlex provides an [example source for  SlideView.](https://slideview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) Download it and see what are you missing.

Comment: Now I have a run time exception

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=Microsoft.Phone
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame..ctor()
       at slidingmenu.App.InitializePhoneApplication()
       at slidingmenu.App..ctor()
  InnerException:

Comment: it's shot it the dark, but probably you try to bind something that doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my (MvvmCross-) app.

I was able to resolve this by creating the RootFrame by code in `App.xaml.cs` instead of adding it in the Xaml:

```
    private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        var slideApplicationFrame = new SlideApplicationFrame
            {
                LeftContent = new LeftView(), 
                RightContent = new RightView()
            };

        this.RootFrame = slideApplicationFrame;
        this.RootVisual = this.RootFrame;

        this.RootFrame.Navigated += this.CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        // Handle navigation failures
        this.RootFrame.NavigationFailed += this.RootFrameNavigationFailed;
    }
```

...and removed the whole `<Application.RootVisual>...</Application.RootVisual>` in `App.xaml`.